# Remove value from array according to time php

Tags: php, arrays

I want to remove some value from array accroding to time,for example i want to remove value which come between 9:30 to 10:30 (time period will dynamicaly), Here is my code

```
$cars=array("09:00","09:30","10:00","10:30","11:00","11:30","12:00","12:30");
```

now And i want array like (because time between 9:30 to 10:30 is booked)

```
$cars=array("09:00","11:00","11:30","12:00","12:30");
```

I tried with following code but removing only start time,How can i do this ?

```
echo "<pre>";print_R($cars);
$pos = array_search('10:30', $cars);
unset($cars[$pos]);
echo "<pre>";print_r($cars);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the start and end times in `$start` and `$end`, you can use [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to remove the booked times like this:

```
    $cars=array("09:00","09:30","10:00","10:30","11:00","11:30","12:00","12:30");
$start = "09:30";
$end = "10:30";
$cars = array_filter($cars, function ($v) use ($start, $end) { 
    return strtotime($v) < strtotime($start) || strtotime($v) > strtotime($end); });
print_r($cars);
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => 09:00 [4] => 11:00 [5] => 11:30 [6] => 12:00 [7] => 12:30 )
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/qvZJT)

Answer (score 1):

Although I do like Nick's method, another way you could do it is using a `foreach` loop and handling the times as integers... some people find this easier to read.

```
$start = 930; // same as '09:30'
$end   = 1030; // same as '10:30'
$cars  = array('09:00','09:30','10:00','10:30','11:00','11:30','12:00','12:30');

foreach ($cars as $key => $time){
  $time = (int)str_replace(':','',$time);

  // Remove if between the two times...
  if ($time >= $start AND $time <= $end) unset($cars[$key]);
}

var_dump($cars);
```

Should return: "09:00", "11:00", "11:30", "12:00", "12:30"

Answer (score 0):

You can try below one as well as.

Convert your time into strtotime and compare and again convert in human-readable format.

```
$cars=array("09:00","09:30","10:00","10:30","11:00","11:30","12:00","12:30");

$dynamicStartTime="09:30";
$dynamicEndTime="10:30";
$a= strtotime($dynamicStartTime);
$b= strtotime($dynamicEndTime);
$newarray=array();
foreach($cars as $key=>$value){
    $c=strtotime($value);
    if($c>=$a && $c<=$b){
      //inbetween result
    }else{
        $newarray[]=date("H:i", $c);
    }
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($newarray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the array is already sorted,

```
$cars=array("09:00","09:30","10:00","10:30","11:00","11:30","12:00","12:30");
for($i=0;$i<count($cars);$i++){
    if($cars[$i]=="09:30"){
        unset($cars[$i+1]);
        break;
    }
}
print_r($cars);
```